# Alter Foreign Key Constraint Primary Key Error

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to drop and recreate a foreign key constraint, but I get an error

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'inventory' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'fkInventory_VendorsInventory'.

I have already gone into the table design for both tables referenced in the code, and ensured that the column being referenced is a primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE inventory_vendors 
    DROP CONSTRAINT fkInventory_VendorsInventory;

ALTER TABLE inventory_vendors
    ADD CONSTRAINT fkInventory_VendorsInventory 
    FOREIGN KEY(itemnum) REFERENCES inventory(itemnum) 
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I have done such a drop and recreation before with no problems at all with another set of tables (unfortunately i don't remember which tables they were).

Comment: Do you have more than one field in the Inventory table specified as the primary key?

Comment: YES. one is `itemnum`, the other is `store_id`

Comment: Then the foreign key must also be of two columns.

Comment: That's called a "composite" primary key, not "two primary key columns".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in comments, you have 2 primary key columns in the `Inventory` table:

> one is `itemnum`, the other is `store_id`

I prepare a sample SQL here: 2 tables created

```
CREATE TABLE inventory 
(
    itemnum INT,
    store_id INT,
    inventoryDesc char(200),
    primary key (itemnum, store_id)
);

CREATE TABLE inventory_vendors 
(
    inventory_vendors int,
    itemnum INT,
    store_id INT,
    VendorDetails varchar(200),
    primary key (inventory_vendors)
);
```

Create Unique constraint for one of the primary key. Here I am creating **UNIQUE constraint** for `itemnum` column

```
ALTER TABLE inventory
ADD CONSTRAINT [IX_inventory] UNIQUE ( [itemnum] )
GO
```

Then execute your script for creating the foreign key constraint on `inventory_vendors` for `itemnum` column and you can drop them as well.

```
ALTER TABLE inventory_vendors
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Inventory_Vendors_Inventory 
        FOREIGN KEY(itemnum) REFERENCES inventory(itemnum) 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE inventory_vendors 
    DROP CONSTRAINT fk_Inventory_Vendors_Inventory;
```

[image]

Hope this might help you..

Comment: But in this case, since `itemnum` is **unique** in `Inventory`, the question really is: why isn't just `Itemnum` on its own the **primary key**?? What's the point of having a compound primary key is one of the columns on its own already is unique??